# Bootstrap Vue: custom border column style and custom border row style on b-table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to have the following behaviour:

1. A border in the middle of the table, that separates the table in two part
2. I want to "group" the row by item, meaning I want a visible separation when the item changes

For the **1**, no problem

```html
<b-table :fields="fields"
           :items="incoherences"
           :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"
  ></b-table>
```

```js
    // (computed property)
    get fields() {
      if (this.incoherences.length === 0) return null
      const fields = Object.keys(this.incoherences[0])
      return fields.map(field => {
        if (field === 'devis2') {
          return {
            key: field,
            tdClass: 'with-left-border',
            thClass: 'with-left-border',
          }
        } else {
          return field
        }
      })
    }
```

We don't see very well, but there is a vertical border between **Date Fin1** and **Devis2** columns. There is also a border between each row.
[image]

In the image, I want to have a border at the bottom item 14 (to kind of group them together) and then group the 15, 16 , 17,... alone. So I did this code

```js
    lastItemIdBrowser = 0
    // (method)
    rowClass(item: Incoherence, type: any) {
      let ret = false
      if (!item || type !== 'row') return
      if (item.item1 !== this.lastItemIdBrowser && this.lastItemIdBrowser !== 0) ret = true
      this.lastItemIdBrowser = item.item1
      if (ret) return 'with-top-border'
    }
```

But it has no effect. To see the desired effect, I have to give the table the **borderless** prop, but then I lost all my other borders:

```html
<b-table :fields="fields"
           :items="incoherences"
           :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"
           borderless
  ></b-table>
```

[image]

Does someone know how to combine those features without loosing the other one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because the border you're seeing isn't actually applied to the `tr`, but the `td` in the table.

So you need to edit your CSS to target the `td` inside the rows instead.

```css
.with-top-border > td {
  border-top: 2px solid black !important;
}
```

---

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        'age',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        { key: 'active', tdClass: 'border border-primary' }
      ],
      items: [
        { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald', active: false },
        { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw', active: false },
        { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson', active: true },
        { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney', active: false },
        { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald', active: true },
        { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw', active: true },
        { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson', active: true },
        { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney', active: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setTbodyTrClass(item) {
      const classes = [];
      if(item.active) classes.push('custom-border');
      return classes;
    }
  }
  })
```

```css
.custom-border > td {
  border-top: 3px solid green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :tbody-tr-class="setTbodyTrClass"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I would be nice if they also had a **tdClass** on each item, like **_cellVariants** but for classes

Comment: @DavidAlvarez That could be nice indeed. However you *can* use the `tdClass` on the [fields definitions](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference) object, which functions similar to `tbody-tr-class`, but you would have to define it on each field which probably isn't very performance friendly.

Comment: Yes but then the style would be applied to all the rows, not the only we want ?!

Comment: @DavidAlvarez `tdClass` accepts a function just like `tbody-tr-class`. Where it passes in the `value` of that cell. The `key` of the field. and `item` of the row. So you can access the `item` just like you do in your `rowClass` function.